# How to identify iPad models: MLQ82FDA and MLYM2FDA?

Tags: ipad

I need to find out what iPads have the order numbers MLQ82FDA and MLYM2FDA. I don't own them and so I do not have the A number available.

I try to identify it using [this Apple Support page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201471) but with no success.

Comment: Can be A1674 or A1675, depending on the cellular standards it supports. I wanted to point you to https://everyi.com/by-identifier/ipod-iphone-ipad-specs-by-apple-order-number-part-number.html but the order numbers you mention aren't even listed there. It's most likely https://everymac.com/systems/apple/ipad/specs/apple-ipad-pro-9-7-inch-1st-gen-wi-fi-cellular-lte-specs.html though.

Answer (score 1):

MLQ82FDA is a **9.7 Inch iPad Pro / Wifi + Cellular / 256 GB / Gold / Year 2016**

- https://www.singular.com.cy/apple-9.7-inch-ipad-pro-wi-fi-cellular-tablet-256gb-9.7-ips-2048-x-1536-4g-gold.html

MLYM2FDA is a **9.7 Inch iPad Pro / WiFi + Cellular / 256 GB / Rose Gold / Year 2016**

- http://pc-tablet.pl/tablet-apple-ipad-pro-9-7-256gb-lte-mlym2fda,3161.html

Your A number can be found by going to Settings -> About then look for Model, then tap the MP number to switch it to an A number.

Comment: Ok, thanks, but what is the difference between them? Only color? What year?

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk edited post on how to find a  number

Comment: The point is that I DO NOT own that ipad;) I need to buy one of them, and I need to see the difference, because there is a huge difference in price;)

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk both are year 2016